# Will microSHIFT ADVENT 9 speed handle 46t, 50t large sprockets?

Tags: drivetrain, alternative-drivetrain

Title says it all.

As we have 11-50t 9 speed cassetes available now, I was curious if anyone tried to use them with microSHIFT advent? or I have to be the first one to try it out?

That would be great wide range and inexpensive setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Five or so years ago the only way to go 1x without mortgaging the house and selling your children was to cobble together a 10speed with a derailleur extension and/or rad cage mod. The success factor was variable at best - as often as not you ended up with an XT priced setup with Acera like shifting. While a few such adaptions were successful, many were quietly rolled back 11-36 cassettes (with out with keeping the 1x, or upgraded to 1x11.   These solutions are still available (for some reason I have yet to figure out).

First problem - Hard tail or squshie? Squishes sometimes have effective chain stay growth, so you end up with a chain too short for the 50 or too long for the 11. If the chain is too short and you hit a big bump hard enough, things break.

Now you can get very cost effective 11-50 1x setups, there would be little advantage going for a Advent 9 speed 11-50. Its unlikely to end up shifting particularly well, and if you can get it to, will get finicky once components get just a little worn out. 
[You may be interested in this Q](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/fitting-a-9-speed-11-50t-cassette-on-mtb-which-derailleur).

The problem is 9 speed 46 tooth (do they even exist) would have a big jump between gears. 50 would be worse. You may get away with it using a  Derailleur Hanger Extension, but as they say YMMV....

I would recommend sticking with a 2x9 or 3x9 until you can afford to go to a 1x10 or better (1x11 or 1x12) with a derailleur designed for big cassettes.

Comment: Have experience with 10 speed experiments with larger cassetes.) Had this question because microSHIFT advent supports 42t cassetes, so not far off for 46t

Answer (score 3):

They do not officially support it.
Even on the long cage version the maximum supported sprocket size is 42t.

https://www.microshift.com/en/product/rd-m6195l/

Comment: Thanks! But i'm interested if **anyone** tried it. Long cage VS medium doesn't help on sprocket size. Only amount of extra chain lenght it can handle for 2x/3x drivetrains.
as it supports 42t, 46t is not far off. For exampe, derraileurs for 36t usually can handle 40t pretty well.

Comment: When going outside the manufacturers maximum limit, its probably going to come down to your individual frame and derailleur hanger.
Due to the nature of this site, you are more likely to generate votes to close due to too broad/personal opinion than "works for me" type answers.

Comment: @ulikus Despite not being specifically off-topic 'has anyone tried this?' type questions so not work very well here, especially ones as specific as yours.